# How to read all the information of a request and to reuse them to make another request?

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that calls another page and I'd like to transfer all the information / headers of the original request to that call.

I found `file_get_contents` to make the request and build the http request context with `stream_context_create`.

I found `getallheaders` and `get_headers` but not sure of the difference. I am also aware of `$_REQUEST` to get the request information.

Is there a straightforward way to get the information of the original request that will work in `stream_context_create` directly to make the new request?

```
# Parse the request
$method = ...
$headers = ...
# something else? cookie / IP?

# Build the request reusing the information from the original request
$opts = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => $method,
        "header" => $headers
    ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$text = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: `get_headers()` gets the response headers of the external URL, what you need is `getallheaders()`.

Comment: Sounds like you are creating a proxy on PHP. If so, take a look on using `curl`: https://dzone.com/articles/building-simple-api-proxy

Comment: Is there a simple way without installing dependencies? I am in an environment where I cannot install any libraries.